# Changing the defult directory structure

Tags: distributions, directory-structure, small-distribution, lfs

If I start a new distro (e.g. [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/)):

1. How can I change the directory structure?
2. What should I expect after it's ready? (probably can't install most of the packages without modification, right?

But, before you down vote: I've been asked to make a new distro for a specific project which they need (actually, want) a new directory structure with a few changes, for example remove the `var` and `bin` directories, but without halting the system. The application of this distro is so limited, so i think it shouldn't be a big deal as they need just a few packages to be installed.

Comment: you compile the components with the appropriate settings and provide customized configuration files for runtime settings.

Comment: @UlrichDangel Thanks, but is there any place where it's better to start from there? for example `kernel` package and this and that config files?

Comment: the kernel doesn't really care about your file system layout and tbh I don't really see the reason why you want to do that anyway. if it is for an embedded system just symlink directories etc. you should probably have a look on systems like openwrt

Comment: @UlrichDangel thanks, I will keep looking into the embedded systems of course. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** You don't.

**Long answer:** If you know what you are doing, you certainly can organize the directories in whatever way you want, and give them names in Swahili too. But that means that you'd have to adjust *each and every* package you install to use this non-standard layout. You will find that some packages' configuration silently ignores the changes, other will freak out, others will break in entertaining ways. I bet you have much better ways of using your time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see what you mean and I'm totally agree with that! however I'm still interested in this project. Not sure gonna do that finally or not, but would love to have a general idea. By the way, what do you mean by "Short answer: You don't". Do you mean "I can't" or what?

Comment: Oh, you certainly can. It's just that that is for hardened, died-in-the-wool masochists. See the long version of the answer. There just is too much assumptions built into random pieces of software (and "common knowledge" at sites like this one, and all books on system administration) that it is highly impractical.